# read IRC data correctly in Processing

Tags: java, regex, processing, irc

I am trying to read IRC and pull data from individual IRC messages in Processing. You can see the code (also with twitter library, ignore that) and I need some pointers on how I can pull the data out in the format of Nick:Message so it can be displayed in a visualization.

```
    //Twitter

    import twitter4j.conf.*;
    import twitter4j.*;
    import twitter4j.auth.*;
    import twitter4j.api.*;
    import java.util.*;



// Import the net libraries
import processing.net.*;

// Declare a client
Client client;


Twitter twitter;
String searchString = "god";
List<Status> tweets;

String server = "irc.twitch.tv";
String nick = "NugShow";
//String user = "simple_bot";
int port = 6667;
String channel = "#nugshow";
String password = "xx";

String in = "butt";
String checkFor;

//bools
Boolean isLive = false;


    int privMsgIndex;
    int atIndex;
    String playerSubstring;



// The channel which the bot will joString channel = "#irchacks";

int currentTweet;

void setup()
{
    size(800,600);
    frameRate(60);

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xx");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xx");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xx");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xx");

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

    twitter = tf.getInstance();

    getNewTweets();

    currentTweet = 0;

    thread("refreshTweets");
    thread("loopChat");
    connectToServer();



    //IRC
}

void draw()
{ 
  if (client.available() > 0) {  
    String in = client.readString();
    println(in);

  }
  if (isLive == false){
    if (client.available() > 0) {


      }
    } else {

    }

  /*
    fill(0, 40);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);

    currentTweet = currentTweet + 1;

    if (currentTweet >= tweets.size())
    {
        currentTweet = 0;
    }

    Status status = tweets.get(currentTweet);

    fill(200);
    text(status.getText(), random(width), random(height), 300, 200);

    delay(100);

    */
}

void joinChannel() {
  String in = client.readString();
  client.write( "JOIN " + channel + "\n\r" );
  client.clear();
  in = client.readString();
  println(in);
  if (in != null){
     //println("Recieved data");
     println(in);
     //String inString = myClient.readStringUntil(""); 

     isLive = true;
     println(isLive);

  }
}

void connectToServer()
{
  client = new Client(this, server , 6667);
  client.write( "PASS " + password + "\n\r" );
  println(password  + " sent!");
  client.write( "NICK " + nick + "\n\r" );
  println(nick + " sent!");
  joinChannel(); 
}


void getNewTweets()
{
    try 
    {
        Query query = new Query(searchString);

        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

        tweets = result.getTweets();
    } 
    catch (TwitterException te) 
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    } 
}



void refreshTweets()
{
    while (true)
    {
        getNewTweets();

        println("Updated Tweets"); 

        delay(30000);
    }
}

void loopChat()
{
    while (true)
    {

      if (privMsgIndex != 0){

        println(privMsgIndex); 
        //privMsgIndex = privMsgIndex - 15;
        atIndex = in.indexOf("@");
        println(atIndex); 
        //atIndex = atIndex + 1;
        playerSubstring = in.substring(atIndex, privMsgIndex);
        println(playerSubstring);
      } else {
        println("looped"); 
      }



        delay(300);
        client.clear();
        in = null;
    }
}

void keyPressed()
{

}


void tweet()
{
    try 
    {
        Status status = twitter.updateStatus("This is a tweet sent from Processing!");
        System.out.println("Status updated to [" + status.getText() + "].");
    }
    catch (TwitterException te)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ te.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

The chat commands look like this: `:nugshow!nugshow@nugshow.testserver.local PRIVMSG #nugshow :dddd` where nugshow is the username, #nugshow is the channel, and dddd is the message. I need to get it into the format of nugshow: dddd.

there is a lot of header information that I'm not sure how to strip out of client.recieved buffer as well, it looks like this:

```
:testserver.local 001 nugshow :Welcome, GLHF!
:testserver.local 002 nugshow :Your host is testserver.local

:testserver.local 003 nugshow :This server is rather new
:testserver.local 004 nugshow :-
:testserver.local 375 nugshow :-
:testserver.local 372 nugshow :You are in a maze of twisty passages, all alike.
:testserver.local 376 nugshow :>

:nugshow!nugshow@nugshow.testserver.local JOIN #nugshow
:nugshow.testserver.local 353 nugshow = #nugshow :nugshow
:nugshow.testserver.local 366 nugshow #nugshow :End of /NAMES list

:jtv!jtv@jtv.testserver.local PRIVMSG nugshow :HISTORYEND nugshow
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the data you are working with

Comment: Would be nice if you'd `mark the part which is crucial` for you, like where you want to get the data in your desired format and maybe a reason why that isn't possible for you (yet) and examples of `input and your desired output` would be best.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the chat commands look like this:

:nugshow!nugshow@nugshow.testserver.local PRIVMSG #nugshow :dddd

where nugshow is the username, #nugshow is the channel, and dddd is the message. I need to get it into the format of nugshow: dddd

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend regex here. At least not if you want to be able to catch all types of IRC messages. The key is to look at the message code to know what you can actually get out of the message. As I'm also writing an IRC-client (just for giggles) I have some notes for you.

Be sure to answer any PINGs that the server sends you so you don't get kicked off. As the PING is sent with an identifier, you need to catch that and send it back. A simple way to do this is to check the last line that was sent from the server and substring it.

```
String line = inputStream.readLine();
if(line.substring(0,4).equals("PING")){
    send("PONG " + line.substring(5)); // Assume you have some send-function.
}
```

This will make sure you don't get kicked off and can proceed to actually stay on a server.

As I mentioned, I do not recommend using regex for this as it would become a RegEx-of-doom. So, what I have done is to just split the line you get and put all the results in a String array.

```
String[] arr = line.split(" ");
```

As you know by your own message line you have posted, the IRC protocol separates things with spaces. So splitting at spaces in not all that shabby (we'll get how to deal with actual text in a bit).
The basic structure that is always the same (as far as I can tell) in messages is PREFIX COMMAND PARAM PARAM/TRAILING. So what does this mean? The PREFIX is where the message was sent from. Example ":user!user@host.com". The COMMAND is what the line actually is. You are looking for PRIVMSG here, but there are many, many, others that you might want to take care of. Like JOIN, PART, QUIT, 332 (current topic), 353 (nicks in channel, 404 (unable to send to channel), etc. etc. The PARAM and PARAM/TRAILING will all depend on the COMMAND.

So, what do we gain from splitting at spaces? This:

```
arr[0] = :user!user@host.com
arr[1] = COMMAND
arr[2] = PARAM
arr[3 onwards] = rest
```

We can now easily manage every command in it's own needed way.

Without further delay, lets get to your actual question, the PRIVMSG.
I will use this string: ":Chewtoy!chewtoy@stackoverflow.com PRIVMSG #stackoverflow :Ty: I saw your question and thought I should give you an answer."
After doing a split at the spaces, we get the array

```
arr[0] = :Chewtoy!chewtoy@stackoverflow.com
arr[1] = PRIVMSG
arr[2] = #stackoverflow
arr[3] = :Ty:
arr[4] = I
arr[5] = saw
...
```

As you can see, everything from 3 and onwards is the message you want. 0-2 is stuff that you need to be able to know who sent what where. My code for getting all this looks like this:

```
String[] arr = receivedLine.split(" ");
if(arr[1].equals("PRIVMSG")){
    String[] usr = arr[0].split(!"); // Get the user, which is in usr[0]. Host in usr[1]
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=3; i<arr.length; i++){ // We know the message starts at arr[3], so start counting from that.
        msg.append(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    String chan = "";
    if(arr[2].substring(0,1).equals("#")){ // We need to differentiate between sending to channel and sending a PM. The only difference in this is where the text is sent.
        chan = arr[2];
    } else{
        chan = usr[0].substring(1); // substring(1) because we want Chewtoy, not :Chewtoy
    }

    // The result here will be: 
    // <#stackoverflow> Chewtoy: Ty: I saw your question and thought I should give you an answer.
    sendItAllToWhereYouWantIt("<" + chan +"> " + usr[0].substring(1) + ": " + msg.substring(1));
}
```

Hope that helps.